# Failed to decode downloaded font in Meteor

Tags: css, meteor, fonts

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'geometria_lightlight';
    src: url('Geometria-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Geometria-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Geometria-Light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Geometria-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Geometria-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Geometria-Light-webfont.svg#geometria_lightlight') format('svg');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;

}

#logo{
  font-family: 'geometria_lightlight';
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

This is the message I am getting in Chrome: 
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/Geometria-Light-webfont.woff2
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/Geometria-Light-webfont.woff

I get this message with every single font that I download via Font Squirrel.

Comment: I am also getitng this, the error only relate to .woff font files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stick your fonts in the folder `public/fonts`.

And then do something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
  src: url('/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any insight in to why this happens? Thank you

Comment: `public` is where Meteor will search for assets. Does that help?

Comment: there is no public folder in meteor anymore.

Comment: The question only relates to the .woff2 file.

Comment: There is still a public folder in Meteor. Create it at the root level of your project. And @JoePrivett the same answer applies to .woff2 format.

Comment: What if the CSS is part of a package (whereby the CSS file cannot be placed in the public folder)?

Comment: The package should handle it. If you're writing the package, I think you use addAssets in the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

After trying lots of other approaches, and lots of re-installs and checking within meteor and npm configurations, I have just fixed the issue by clearing out browsing data from Chrome (cached images and files) and then refreshing the page.