# Font face error: Failed to decode downloaded font invalid version tag

Tags: css, node.js, font-face

Environment is a React Nodejs app

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src:
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg') format('svg');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src:
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.eot'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/src/public/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.svg') format('svg');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
} ....
```

I have two different definitions for Open Sans as the `font-style` and `font-weight` depends on additional classes on elements like bold italic etc which seems to be an [acceptable fomat](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/)

Usage:

```
.union {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding-left: 12px;

  & :global(.bold) {
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  & :global(.italic) {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

Webpack config:

```
test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
```

I have the font files under `public/fonts` folder, it was working fine up until a day ago but now we are getting tons of console errors `failed to decode downloaded font invalid version tag` for **woff** and **ttf** files. I tried other solutions [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288778/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-ots-parsing-error-invalid-version-tag-rails) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767727/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-in-meteor) but it didn't help. I can see the fonts loading just fine from the public folder under Chrome's network tab

Any idea why am still getting these errrors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the error. It was a combination of a couple things.. first was the path to the font file, I was setting the path as if there was no “build” happening, Webpack was putting them under `/assets` after release build so I had to update my path from `src/public/fonts` to `/fonts` as after the build static files are automagically looked under assets folder + adding regex to support versioning in my webpack loader config + adding mimetype for `woff` files